# Strange behaviour of Android Studio at launching the JUnit test from the popup menu

Tags: android, debugging, testing, android-studio, junit

I have a simple test, here is the start of it.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class BanknotesCountingTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("before test");
    }
.....
```

If I launch it **from the toolbar** of Android Studio, it runs OK, printing the "before test" line and later launching all tests. The debugging can be launched by the bug icon.

If I am **right clicking** on it in the Projects view and choose **"run ..." in the popup menu**, it shows the green OK button, with no tests in it. No output to console, no stop at any breakpoint works if I launch it as "debug ...", also from popup menu. It seems, the test file doesn't run really, but AS simulates the good results.

Obviously, these two ways of launching are different. But what is that difference?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, I have found my error.

I have changed the test from a testNG one, and two Run configurations remained as the result. By right click the obsolete testNG configuration was launched (don't know why). And in the toolbar the JUnit configuration was chosen. And I launched it, clicking on the "Run" triangle.